# Max/Min Problem using derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Question: A professional basketball team plays in an arena that holds 20000 spectators. Average attendance at each game has been 14000. The average ticket price is 75 dollars. Market research shows that, for each $5 reduction in the ticket price, attendance increases by 800. Find the price that will maximize revenue.

My work so far (which is not giving me the right answer):

Let x be the number of $5 reductions.

R = (75 - x)(14000 + 800x)

R = 1050000 + 46000x - 800x^2

dR/dx = 46000 - 1600x

For max revenue:

when dR/dx = 0:

x = 28.75

when dR/dx DNE:

x = NULL

This is obv. wrong because how can there be 28.75 $5 reductions?

Can someone please help out?

Thanks!

Comment: When you are talking about a continuous/differentiable function, you are talking about a function of a *real variable*, and it is in this situation that the minimization/maximization problem can be solved in terms of derivatives. What you have is a function of an *integer variable* and a smooth interpolation of this function

Comment: I don't know what you said but this is what I am supposed to do (Gr 12 Calculus)

Comment: In any case, your computation basically shows that the maximum is around the real number 28.75. So which integer is it: 28 or 29? And how can you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $(75-5x)\times(14000+800x)$.
 Because decreasing is by \$5  x times.

The number of spectators increases by 800 for every \$5 but not for every \$1.

Comment: ok, but why 5x when i said that x is the number of $5 reductions?

Comment: ok, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Wait, then how come you don't multiply the 800 by 5?

Comment: I got -1.25, why is this negative?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But you know that x is between 0 and 15. Therefore the function is decreasing in the interval [0,15] and you have to take x=0, that is not to change te ticket  price in order to have maximum revenue,

Comment: R x
1050000 0
1036000 1
1014000 2
984000 3
946000 4
900000 5
846000 6
784000 7
714000 8
636000 9
550000 10
456000 11
354000 12
244000 13
126000 14
0 15

Comment: so what is the answer?

Comment: the answer is x=0 then R=1050000

Comment: actually, no it is not. I spent the last hour staring at my page and just realizing that since x = -1.25, and my let statement states that "blah blah REDUCTIONS!", it means that there is actually an increase in the ticket price by 6.25, and the right answer is $81.25. The textbook answers also agree. But anyways, thanks for your help!!!!!!